# Spatial merge of two sf objects

Tags: r, r-sf

I am trying to merge the two dataframes (main and sub). I want the 'variable' data from 'sub' to be merged to 'main' based on distance or better yet, whichever 'sub' row/site is closest to the 'main' row/site.

```
library(sf)

a <- structure(list(`Site#` = c("Site1", "Site2", "Site3", "Site4", "Site5", "Site6"), Longitude = c(-94.609, -98.1391, -99.033, -98.49, -96.4309, -95.99), `Latitude` = c(38.922, 37.486111, 37.811, 38.364, 39.4402, 39.901)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

main <- st_as_sf(a, coords = c("Longitude", "Latitude"), crs = 4326)

b <- structure(list(Longitude = c(-98.49567, -96.22451, -98.49567, -98.941391, -95.91411, -99.031113), `Latitude` = c(38.31264,39.97692, 38.31264, 37.486111, 39.92143, 37.814171), Variable = c(400, 50, 100, 201, 99, 700)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

sub <- st_as_sf(b, coords = c("Longitude", "Latitude"), crs = 4326)

c <- st_intersection(main,sub)
c <- st_is_within_distance(main,sub,dist=0.001)
```

I believe that the st_intersection is what I want, but if I could do it one-to-one based on distance, that would make it work. Does anyone know what could provide the result I am looking for?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`st_join()` allows for joining in a single step:

```r
st_join(main, sub, join = st_nearest_feature, left = T)


#> although coordinates are longitude/latitude, st_nearest_feature assumes that they are planar
#> Simple feature collection with 6 features and 2 fields
#> geometry type:  POINT
#> dimension:      XY
#> bbox:           xmin: -99.033 ymin: 37.48611 xmax: -94.609 ymax: 39.901
#> epsg (SRID):    4326
#> proj4string:    +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>   `Site#`            geometry Variable
#>   <chr>           <POINT [°]>    <dbl>
#> 1 Site1      (-94.609 38.922)       99
#> 2 Site2   (-98.1391 37.48611)      201
#> 3 Site3      (-99.033 37.811)      700
#> 4 Site4       (-98.49 38.364)      400
#> 5 Site5    (-96.4309 39.4402)       50
#> 6 Site6       (-95.99 39.901)       99
```

<sup>Created on 2020-01-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: This is more concise so I will give this the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is what I tried. It seems that you need `st_nearest_feature()`, which gets index of nearest feature. Once you have indices, you add them to `main`. You also add row numbers (the indices) to `b`. Then, you want to handle join.

```
library(dplyr)
library(sf)

# Which feature in y is closest to each feature in x?
# You get row index
st_nearest_feature(x = main, y = sub)

# Add the index number to main.
mutate(main, ind = st_nearest_feature(x = main, y = sub)) -> main

# Add row numbers (index) to b
mutate(b, ind = 1:n()) -> b

left_join(main, b, by = "ind")

#  `Site#`            geometry   ind Longitude Latitude Variable
#  <chr>           <POINT [°]> <int>     <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#1 Site1      (-94.609 38.922)     5     -95.9     39.9       99
#2 Site2   (-98.1391 37.48611)     4     -98.9     37.5      201
#3 Site3      (-99.033 37.811)     6     -99.0     37.8      700
#4 Site4       (-98.49 38.364)     1     -98.5     38.3      400
#5 Site5    (-96.4309 39.4402)     2     -96.2     40.0       50
#6 Site6       (-95.99 39.901)     5     -95.9     39.9       99
```

Comment: Great answer! Works perfectly.

Comment: @FISHnR I am glad to hear that. I hope you can keep rolling in your task. :)